# Avoid android app freeze when in background

Tags: android, service

I have implemented a started `Service` which is intended to continue running in the background (`onStartCommand returns START_STICKY`). On a 5.1 device I found that swiping the current task from the Recent Tasks kills the `Service` and it is not restarted which is not the case on a 4.2 device.

The workarounds suggested on SO to set an alarm to restart the `service` after 1s too did not work.

After some researching, I figured out that under the `BATTERY` settings, we have options to specify whether or not to freeze applications when in the background. The default behaviour is to freeze the background execution.

Are there any specific `permissions` that I need to seek to allow the app to continue running in the background?

Comment: EDIT: The service has been implemented with startForeground(). It is known problem that post 4.4 the service gets killed when the app is swiped off the recents screen. While some suggestions have been posted they have not worked out for me. However, I did find that there is this specific toggle that helps. I am not sure if we can overcome this programmatically and hence my request for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid background problems, you need to avoid ui updates in the

```
protected void onPause() {
```

function of your activity.

if your using a service
For Android 2.0 or later you can use the `startForeground()` method to start your Service in the foreground.

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a
>   candidate for killing when low on memory.